# Minimal Windows 8 C++ XAML application?

Tags: windows-8

If i used "create blank C++ XAML application" in Visual Studio 2012 Express, the created project has 18 files with more that 25 kilobytes of source code. Looking on that code it's hard to separate what is required for Windows 8 application and what is written just because manager in charge for sample apps read some "best practice patterns for leviathan enterprise apps" book recently :).

So maybe anyone knows, what is the source code of minimum working C++ XAML Windows 8 app that can be compiled with msbuild and displays a "hello world" window?

Comment: Why don't you use a template? They care about anything that could go wrong to make life easier and it's just waiting to be filled with your amiable code. Do you really care about 25kb?

Comment: @Michael, using a template is fine. But I think that before using a template it is better to learn the basics. Knowing the minimum required code for creating such application is the basics. This way you understand what happens under the covers of a template. I've seen many people relying on some templates without understanding what those templates are doing and asking stupid questions on StackOverflow because they didn't learn the basics. So I completely agree with the approach that the OP has taken. +1 to his question. And yeah, it seems ridiculous to need 25kb for a Hello World Application.

Comment: I love C++ but I think you'd be better off with C# for a new Metro application. And if you're serious, [pick up a copy of Programming Windows Sixth Edition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/08/16/10340193.aspx) for cheap, now.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, that's only your opinion. There are people that love C++ (even if that might sound weird to you and me :-)) and would pick it for developing Metro style applications. But that's not what's being asked here so let's not get off-topic but focus on the actual question.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I know WinAPI pretty well. Unfortunately, it don't have anything with WinRT and XAML subset used for "metro apps" :(. Completely different beast.

Comment: The entire book is on Metro apps...

Comment: @ta.speot.is This changes everything. I liked original "programming windows", so i will buy this new one right now. Thanks a lot! But it's C#, so this question is stll important for me. I need C++ for some projects.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I only found 11kb worth of code in a blank C++ metro template.

Comment: XAML and .sln are also kind of... code :). XAML is compiled into code and .sln / .vcproj contains compilation and linking directives.

Comment: xaml is code, but sly and vcproj contain compilation instructions.  That would be like saying a Make file is code.  Maybe technically true, but I don't consider it code because it has no affect on the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can tell you from C#, which the folder structure should be similar to C++.

- **Required**: Properties -> Holds the Assembly Info.
- **Required**: References -> Holds the necessary frameworks for metro & .NET.
- **Optional?**: Assets -> Holds the Splash Screen Images & Icons. If you dereference them I guess you can remove them.
- **Optional?**: Common -> Holds the Standard XAML Styles. I suppose if you don't need to use them you can remove them.
- **Required**: App.xaml -> Handles the startup and
  management of the W8 App.

Tell me if you can see any of these files in your C++ Project.